# How to load .npz file into Google Compute Engine

Tags: numpy, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, jupyter

I have a CNN model I'd like to run in a Jupyter interface that is connected to a VM instance in Google Compute Engine.  I've been having trouble figuring out how to read the data from Jupyter and have converted the photo image data into an .npz file that is saved in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def load_dataset():

    # load dataset

    data = load('gs://bucket/data.npz')
    X, y = data['arr_0'], data['arr_1']

    # separate into train and test datasets
    trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
    print(trainX.shape, trainY.shape, testX.shape, testY.shape)
    return trainX, trainY, testX, testY
```

I figured I could use the gsutil functions to alias the path to the bucket and file but get an error saying no such file exists.

Here is the full traceback:

[image]

Comment: If the error occurs in the `load` statement (it's a good idea to show the full message and traceback), then the rest of the code is superfluous.  You need to focus on getting the right path and/or download from the source.

Comment: Please provide us background on the `load` function you're using.

Answer (score 0):

We could suggest you two different ways.

One is having Python calling `gsutil` to [download a Cloud Storage object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) to your file system and then work with that data.

Or you could use a [Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) which is arguably a better approach.

For the latter, make sure you've run `pip install google-cloud-storage` in the past on the machine you're running your code.

Assuming the `load` function you're using takes as input a file in the current working directory.

Add the following snippet to your source code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()

def download_gcs_object(name_bucket, name_blob):
    bucket = client.bucket(name_bucket)
    blob = bucket.blob(name_blob)
    blob.download_to_filename(blob.name)
    print("Downloaded into current working directory a file with name ", blob.name)
```

After this you can edit the piece you've posted this way:

```
def load_dataset():

    #download a Cloud Storage object
    BUCKET="bucket" #TODO edit
    BLOB="data.npz" #TODO edit
    #or #BUCKET, BLOB = 'gs://bucket/data.npz'.split('/')[-2:] #if you prefer, have to edit accordingly again
    download_gcs_object(BUCKET, BLOB)

    # load dataset from filename with the blob name 

    data = load(BLOB)
    #The rest of the code is as it was...
    X, y = data['arr_0'], data['arr_1']

    # separate into train and test datasets
    trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
    print(trainX.shape, trainY.shape, testX.shape, testY.shape)
    return trainX, trainY, testX, testY
```

Let us know if this works, if it doesn't explain what's the `load` function.